# How to remove permissions of other chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have 2 different chrome extensions and I want one of them to take away the permissions of the other. For example there is extension A and extension B, I want extension A to remove the permissions of extension B without extension B having to do anything (I dont want extension B to have to do anything to remove its own permissions). Is this possible?

Comment: What's your use case for this?